# Facebook Friend List Import using fboauth, see for local account and display using views

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal, drupal-7

I am using fboauth for enabling login with facebook for the website. Here is an overview of how I achieve the functionality:

When the user clicks on the facebook login button on the website, he or she is taken to a facebook login page. After logging in with facebook, the user is taken to the app authorization page where the user asks for permission to connect with the app. Once necessary permissions are granted, a local account (account at my website) is automatically created for the user and the user is brought back to a welcome page to set password. The user won't even have to verify their email address. On subsequent visits, when the user clicks on the login link, he/she is taken to the same facebook login page where they supply their login credentials. On successful login, they are brought back to the website. So far, everything works fine with the [fboauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth) module.

What I am trying to achieve now is a functionality similar to what is found with the [fbconnect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect) module. The user is provided with a block/page where the user can import the list of his friends who has authorized with the app, and see the links to their local accounts (accounts at the website). How to achieve this functionality? The fboauth module has its own API which can be utilized. Here is what I already have, written using the API of fboauth.

```
<?php
module_load_include('inc', 'fboauth', 'includes/fboauth.fboauth');
module_load_include('module', 'fboauth', 'fboauth');
module_load_include('php', 'fboauth', fboauth.api');
module_load_include('inc', 'fboauth', 'includes/fboauth.field');
module_load_include('inc', 'fboauth', 'includes/fboauth.pages');
module_load_include('inc', 'fboauth', 'includes/fboauth.profile');
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['my-friends'] = array(
    'title' => t('Your Friends'),
    'page callback' => 'friend_import',
    'access callback' => TRUE;
  );
  return $items;
}
function friend_import() {
          $result = fboauth_graph_query('me/friends?fields=id', $access_token);
          drupal_set_message(t('Import complete!'));
          $accounts = array();
          $output = "";
          foreach($result->data as $fbuid){
            $accounts[] = user_load(fboauth_uid_load($fbuid->id));
            $output = l($account->name, "/user/" . $account->uid);
          }
          dpm($accounts);


   return $output;
}
```

This will import all the friends of a user who have authenticated for the app as an object into $result (having name and user id). However, what I am finding it difficult is to display those names with the user's corresponding local accounts (accounts at the website). This is because of my lack of knowledge in php. What I am looking for is here is the exact lines of code that can be inserted after $result recieves its value so that the names of the users are displayed along with the links to their profile pages at the website.

Comment: With API v2 you will not get all of a user’s friends any more, but only those that are users of your app already.

Comment: @CBroe that is exactly what I am looking for. I would also like a way to display the list along with the links to their local accounts.

Comment: I have edited the question for better clarity.

Comment: I understand you need to match FB user with Drupal user. What is your key here? Did you store facebook user id into a drupal profile field? With that, you may do match!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, if you look at the fbconnect module, you will see that there is a table that contains both the fid and uid (FB's and Drupal's). There is also a function you can user, to save you from the work of writing the query yourself:

```
/**
 * Load a Drupal User ID given a Facebook ID.
 */
function fboauth_uid_load($fbid) {
  $result = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {fboauth_users} WHERE fbid = :fbid", array(':fbid' => $fbid));
  $uid = $result->fetchField();
  return $uid ? (int) $uid : FALSE;
}
```

So, in order to get all friends, you would first need to call the the function that returns user's friends in FB:

```
$result = fboauth_graph_query('me/friends?fields=id', $access_token);
```

Then, iterate through that $result and get the local data:

```
$accounts = array();
  foreach($result->data as $fbuid){
    $accounts[] = user_load(fboauth_uid_load($fbuid->id));
  }
```

So far, I think you had already figured this out.

Next thing we do, depends on how you want the module to behave. If you need a custom page, with an url, implement hook_menu to create that page:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['desired/path'] = array(
    'title' => t('My friends'),
    'page callback' => 'fb_friends',    <-- This function you need to create now
     ....
  );

function fb_friends() {

          $result = fboauth_graph_query('me/friends?fields=id', $access_token);

          $accounts = array();
          $output = "";
          foreach($result->data as $fbuid){
            $accounts[] = user_load(fboauth_uid_load($fbuid->id);
            $output .= l($account->name, "/user/" . $account->uid) . </br>;
          }

          return $output;
}
```

For better formatting, instead of building the $output yourself, you would call `theme_table`, that does it for you: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7

Lastly, I recommend saving the relationships to a user and his friends in a local table, so next time you don't have to go to FB. I think you can take it from the example above. If your problem is showing the friends, it will do, although not very efficient because of going to FB everytime. Hope it helps.

Comment: The function is defined in includes/fboauth.fboauth.inc  inside the fboauth module. So include that file before calling the function, with require(drupal_get_path('module', 'fboauth') . '/' . íncludes/fboauth.fboauth.inc');

Comment: I used the module_load_include and called for the file, but still I am getting the "call to undefined function fboauth_graph_query" error. The way I did, I have shown in the code of your answer as an edit.

Comment: I made it work, but now there is "Notice: Undefined variable: access_token " error.

Comment: I edited the code in your answer, but looke like the moderator removed it. Now, I have edited the code in my question. It is bringing a Notice: Undefined variable: access_token error.

Answer (score 0):

You need either a user id or name or email to match Drupal's corresponding fields. These three fields are unique for a Drupal site. Unless the query to FB return any of those, you won't be able to map a FB user to a Drupal user.

Provided that the name or the user id are the same for drupal app, you can do:

```
$output = "";
foreach ($result as $u) {
   $output .= $u->name , "<br>";    //or $u->id for the id
}

return $output;
```

This will work if A) $result contains a list of objects, B) Those are the exact field names.

The other issue is that if you want a custom page with the output, you need to implement the hook_menu so you can provide such custom page in your module.

I recommend you install the Devel module for easily inspection your data. After you install it and enable it, just call `dsm($result)` from your code, so you have a nice view of what is in the $result variable.

And before actually building that into a module, try simply adding a basic Drupal page, set the format to PHP and write that code, so you can test easily and then move that into the module.

So to recap, the first thing to do is to find out what comes in that variable and in which structure. Then, if any of those fields have the same value for the local users, just write the hook_menu and provide a custom page within your module.

Provided that you have, say, the user id (Drupal's Id)  you can build a link to the user account by printing `$output .= '<a href="/user/' . $id . '">' . $name . '</a><br>';` and then `return $output;`

If you give me the $result content here, I might come up with a better solution.

Comment: I have progressed since I asked this question. I have edited my question with my new lines of code. My graph query calls now brings the user's fbids that are then converted into their facebook user ids. However, I could not yet print it though. The value of $result is [here](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0873jh8cfe). I started a similar question at [drupal stackexchange](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130208/facebook-friend-list-import-using-fboauth) where an answer reached a dead end where neither me not the person who answered knew how to print it.